# Android TabActivity instance in ViewGroup's chaild Activity

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have TabHost app with Three Activities,in first tab i created a viewGroup.every thing working fine
**my problem is i want to get TabActivity instance from the view group's chaild Activity
How can i get this... i am trying like this in View group's child activity**

```
Tab_Activity TabObj = (Tab_Activity)getParent();
abObj.someMethod();
```

i got Class Cast Exception,i think i am  getting View group Activity instance,
i want to get TabActivity instance,please help me if any one knows answer

```
 Tab_Activity TabObj = (Tab_Activity)getParent().getParent();
```

treid like this also...
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it: if your TabActivity properly extends the standard `android.app.TabActivity` then `Tab_Activity TabObj = (Tab_Activity)getParent();` should work as designed.

EDIT: AH. You want to do something like this:

```
Tab_Activity TabObj = (Tab_Activity)((ChildActivity)getContext()).getParent();
```

from inside the ViewGroup.